# Trouble adding string before fields in read-only SQL

Tags: sql

**Trouble**

Adding 'Type ' and 'Code ' before fields contained in Reason to a read only database.

**The Original Question**

A `Union` operator will need to be used here. A certain creditcode and jobtype will need to be found, see the bugged code below.

My code:

```
SELECT cust_id, creditcode as 'Reason'
FROM publishers
WHERE creditcode IS 'D'
UNION 
SELECT cust_id, jobtype as 'Reason'
FROM bookjobs
WHERE jobtype IS 'R';
```

Gives:

```
cust_id     Reason
----------  ----------
A01         R
D04         D
E05         R
```

However, needed is:

```
cust_id     Reason
----------  ----------
A01         Type R
D04         Code D
E05         Type R
```

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Homework? Hint: String concatenate `'Type '` to `jobtype` and `'Code'` to `creditcode`. Look up the documentation of your DBMS on how this is done.

Comment: Not sure what RDBMS or DBMS is being used. Inputting source code to CodeRunner and clicking "Check" to see if answer is correct. This program does not recognise CONCAT, maybe that gives a hint on version. Wish I knew the management system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `PostgreSQL`, you can do it as below, where `||` does the string concatenation. I added `ORDER BY` clause for sorting too.

```
SELECT
    cust_id, 
    'Code ' || creditcode as 'Reason'
FROM publishers
WHERE creditcode = 'D'

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    cust_id, 
    'Type ' || jobtype as 'Reason'
FROM bookjobs
WHERE jobtype = 'R'

ORDER BY cust_id;
```

For `mysql`, you can use `CONCAT()` function:

```
SELECT
    cust_id, 
    CONCAT('Code ' , creditcode) as 'Reason'

FROM publishers
WHERE creditcode = 'D'

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    cust_id,
    CONCAT('Type ' , jobtype) as 'Reason'

FROM bookjobs
WHERE jobtype = 'R'

ORDER BY cust_id;
```

Comment: Use `UNION ALL`, not `UNION`.  There is no reason to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  True actually, edited my answer. Thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: Thank you so much Shuwn! The first one worked! I have another question I have just added to my profile 2 minutes ago.

Comment: If my answer helps, why not mark it as answer then :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT cust_id, 'CODE ' || creditcode as Reason
FROM publishers
WHERE creditcode = 'D'
UNION ALL
SELECT cust_id, 'TYPE ' || jobtype as Reason
FROM bookjobs
WHERE jobtype = 'R';
```

Notes:

- `||` is the ANSI standard string concatenation operator.  Some databases have alternative methods, such as `CONCAT()` or `+`.
- Use `UNION ALL` rather than `UNION` -- unless you specifically want to incur the overhead of removing duplicates.
- `=` is the traditional way of comparing values in SQL, not `IS`.
- Do not include column aliases in single quotes.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: Hello Gordon, your source code worked wonders. Thank you. I have amended another question to my profile 4 minutes ago, in case you are in a question answering mood.